# MVC Entity Framework Generic Get Next Int

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create in my repository a generic function to get the next highest Int in a column called Order.  I think I have the method correct but am not sure how to actually call it.

```
namespace MyApp.Data.Models.Core.Repositories
{
    public interface INextOrder
    { 
        int AppID { get; set; }
        int Order { get; set; }
    }
}

public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, INextOrder
{
    public int NextFind(TEntity predicate, int appID)
    {
        int result = 0;

        var count = Context.Set<TEntity>().Count();

        if (count != 0)
        {
            result = (from List in Context.Set<TEntity>()
                      where List.AppID == appID
                      orderby List.Order
                      select List.Order).ToList().LastOrDefault();

            result++;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Edit: The NextFind method will search for the currently greatest Int value in the Order table, increment it by one and then return that value. It's parameters need to be what Entity Framework entity class to search and also an integer value for filtering purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make an extension method so you can call

`entity.NextFind(5);`

if that is the case you should update the class to be static then you method should look like this

`public static int NextFind(this TEntity predicate, int appID)`

Comment: I realized, thanks to your answer, that I was over thinking this. My method definition needed to be:

public int NextFind(int appID)

Comment: Unfortunately my fixed appeared to work until I rebuilt my solution. I am now getting the error that There is no implicit reference conversion from the class (Tentity) to INextOrder.

Comment: @user3140169, open another question with the class definitions and someone will definitely give you some help (i will if i get to it first but doubt it lol).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to manually handle the order numbers which I would recommend against because it can cause problems.

For example, if two users (A and B) use this method within a very short period of time they will both be using the same int as their orderID / num  and after user A saves his/her order user B would be causing trouble when s/he attempts to save their order because s/he will be using the same orderID / num which doesn't seem to be what you are looking for.

Why not let SQL handle this with an identity field instead?

Comment: The order is only for display order of items. You do have a valid point but there is very little chance that their would be more than one user per AppID altering the order at any given time.